# I can't install anyting using NPM

Tags: npm, npm-install

verbose node v16.14.2

verbose npm  v8.5.5

error code 1

error path C:\Users\DRUID\Desktop\Test\node_modules\es5-ext

error command failed

error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}"

error "node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�

error ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

verbose exit 1

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! Please check [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you.

Comment: Please provide more information, such as what command you ran at the time, what the exact error messages were and use back ticks for code e.g. `error command failed`

Comment: Hello everybody. I get this error message when I enter: npm i in console.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
All it required, is to install this: npm i es5-ext@0.10.53